# activex component not loading from apache xampp

Tags: php, apache, dll, xampp, activex

I am developing a web app in which fingerprint recognition is being used. I am using XAMPP on windows, working with a SECUGEN fingerprint device and the API provided by them. They gave a sample html file in which they are using activex component to access fingerprint device from the browser. It is working well and good when i try to access through `D:\files\sample.html`. i am getting a prompt that "the current page needs an activex component, when i say 'yes' its ready to use."

But, the problem starts here. I moved that file (sample.html) to htdocs of XAMPP server and tried to access it through `http://localhost/app/sample.html`, the activex component is not being loaded i guess.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ActiveX Example 1.1 of SecuGen FDx Pro SDK </title>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var aaa = 0;
function fnOpenDevice()
{
    for ( i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        document.frmmain.objFP[i].DeviceID = document.frmmain.inc.value;
        document.frmmain.objFP[i].CodeName = document.frmmain.dev.value;
        document.frmmain.objFP[i].MinutiaeMode = document.frmmain.templateFormat.value;
    }

    // template format of objVerify should be the same to those of objFP[]
    objVerify.MinutiaeMode = document.frmmain.templateFormat.value;
    return;
}

function fnCapture(idx)
{
    document.frmmain.objFP[idx].Capture();
    var result = document.frmmain.objFP[idx].ErrorCode;
    if (result == 0)
    {   
        //var strimg1 = objFP.ImageTextData;

        var strmin = document.frmmain.objFP[idx].MinTextData;
        document.frmmain.min[idx].value = strmin;
    }
    else
        alert('failed - ' + result);

    return;
}

function fnRegister()
{
    var strmin1 = document.frmmain.min[0].value;
    var strmin2 = document.frmmain.min[1].value;

    if ( objVerify.RegisterForText(strmin1, strmin2) && objVerify.ErrorCode == 0 )
        alert('success- registered');
    else
        alert('failed - ' + objVerify.ErrorCode);

    return;
}

function fnVerifyEx()
{   
    var strmin1 = document.frmmain.min[0].value;
    var strmin2 = document.frmmain.min[1].value;
    var strmin3 = document.frmmain.min[2].value;

    if ( objVerify.VerifyExForText(strmin1, strmin2, strmin3) && objVerify.ErrorCode == 0)
        alert('Success - matched');
    else
        alert('Failed - ' + objVerify.ErrorCode);

    return;
}

function fnVerify()
{   
    var strmin1 = document.frmmain.min[0].value;
    var strmin2 = document.frmmain.min[2].value;

    if ( objVerify.VerifyForText(strmin1, strmin2) && objVerify.ErrorCode == 0 )
        alert('Success - matched');
    else
        alert('Failed - ' + objVerify.ErrorCode);

    return;
}

function fnSetimage()
{
    document.frmmain.objFP.ImageTextData = document.frmmain.img1.value;

    return;
}
// -->

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h4><b>ActiveX Example 1.1 of SecuGen FDx Pro SDK</b></h4>
<p></p>

<OBJECT id="objVerify" style="LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px" height=0 width=0 
    classid="CLSID:8D613732-7D38-4664-A8B7-A24049B96117" 
    name=objVerify VIEWASTEXT>
</OBJECT>

<form name=frmmain>

Device Type :
<select name="dev">
<option value="0">FDP02
<option value="1">FDU02
<option value="2">FDU03
<option selected value="3">FDU04
<option value="4">FDU05

</select>

Instance No. :
<select name="inc">
<option value="-1">-1   
<option value="0" selected>0
<option value="1">1
<option value="2">2
<option value="3">3
<option value="4">4
<option value="5">5
<option value="6">6
<option value="7">7
<option value="8">8
<option value="9">9
</select>

<p>
Template Format:
<select name="templateFormat">
<option value="256">ANSI 378
<option value="512">SG 400
<option value="768">ISO 19794-2
</select>

<input type="button" name="open" value='Open Device' OnClick='fnOpenDevice();'>
<p>

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<caption> Fingerprint Images </caption>
<tr>
<td>
    <OBJECT id="objFP" style="LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 149px; TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 182px" height="182" 
        width="149" classid="CLSID:D547FDD7-82F6-44e8-AFBA-7553ADCEE7C8" name="objFP" VIEWASTEXT>
    <PARAM NAME="CodeName" VALUE="1">
    </OBJECT>
</td>
<td>
    <OBJECT id="objFP" style="LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 149px; TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 182px" height="182" 
        width="149" classid="CLSID:D547FDD7-82F6-44e8-AFBA-7553ADCEE7C8" name="objFP" VIEWASTEXT>
    <PARAM NAME="CodeName" VALUE="1">
    </OBJECT>
</td>
<td>
    <OBJECT id="objFP" style="LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 149px; TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 182px" height="182" 
        width="149" classid="CLSID:D547FDD7-82F6-44e8-AFBA-7553ADCEE7C8" name="objFP" VIEWASTEXT>
    <PARAM NAME="CodeName" VALUE="1">
    </OBJECT>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><input type="button" name="btnCapture1" value='Capture' OnClick='fnCapture(0);'></td>
<td align="center"><input type="button" name="btnCapture2" value='Capture' OnClick='fnCapture(1);'></td>
<td align="center"><input type="button" name="btnCapture3" value='Capture' OnClick='fnCapture(2);'></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>

min1 : <input type="text" name="min"><br>
min2 : <input type="text" name="min"><br>
min3 : <input type="text" name="min">
<p>
<input type="button" name="btnRegister" value='Register' OnClick='fnRegister();' style='width:200px'>
<br>
<input type="button" name="btnVerify" value='VerifyEx' OnClick='fnVerifyEx();' style='width:200px'>
<br>
<input type="button" name="btnVerify" value='Verify' OnClick='fnVerify();' style='width:200px'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

What may be the problem? Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: Did you have success on this? I have got secugen device, wanted to use it on website but seems like that website is not capturing data. Any way to capture data other than that website?  I needed MinTextData and ImageTextData returned by sdk

Comment: hi @hridayesh have you tried with activex component in internet explorer. please explain your problem clearly. are you not able to access your device or you are not able to get the fingerprint from the device..

Comment: Thanks. I was able to capture. The problem was that I had given wrong device id. I had secugen 3 whose device id is 2 but I was giving 3.

Comment: Hi I am using Hamster pro 20 .sample.html file not working for me.Please can you share how it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add http://localhost to allow site list for activex control in ie.

Following are the step to enable activex control in ie

Start Internet Explorer, click the Tools -> Internet Options.

2. Click the Security tab, and set Medium as the Security level for both Internet and Local intranet zones.
3. Click Custom Level button and ensure that the following are set to Enabled:

Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins

Script ActiveX controls marked safe for scripting

4. Click OK after these settings are enabled.
5. Click the Trusted sites icon and click Sites button.
6. Clear the checkbox before Require server verification (https: ) for all sites in this zone option.
7. Fill your local pages (for example, http://localhost) in the Add this website to the zone field and click Add.
8. Click Close.
9. Click OK again to save your changes.
10. Restart Internet Explorer  and test the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have must have to add https://localhost for allow on your site for active ActiveX control in IE 9 or later version.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add `http://localhost` to allow site list for activex control in ie.